# Unable to connect to remote MySql server from all clients except php

Tags: c#, mysql, remote-server

I have remote server(windows server 2008) with MySql server installed,server has dedicated ip. I can connect on this server from remote php client  using  simple mysqli connection. But I cant connect from my home-PC using all other clients(MySqlWorkBench, C# etc).

To connect from C# I use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

    namespace ConsoleApplication4
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
             {
    
                string server = "servdomain.su";
                string  database = "dbname";
                string  uid = "root";
                string  password = "root";
                string connectionString;
    
                connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3307 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

php code:

```
$host="servdomain.su:3307";
$port=;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$dbname="";

$q = "SHOW DATABASES";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, 'root', 'root', 'dbname');

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM incli_measurements")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
 print_r($mysqli);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
 print_r($mysqli);
 echo "4564654";
 exit;
```

Every time I have:
*Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.*

1. FireWall turned off on client and server
2. Users have all grants on database
3. I've tried with other users not only from root
4. I've tried to change default MySql server port

Comment: PORT=3307? Usually is 3306, did you change it? And why don't you set values for Server and Database keys?

Comment: drivers/connectors installed? http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: 4. I've tried to change default MySql server port. Values I deleted because server is available in internet. There is no mistakes in this parameters

Comment: drivers and connectors installed(on client). C# client use "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"

Comment: Is your C# client a Windows service?

Comment: PHP is a script that runs on your webserver which is probably different than your client machine where you run the C# code from. Keep in mind that MySQL has a privilege system which allows to control form which host machine a user may connect. Check that the user you are using is actually allowed to connect from your client machine. Also, a copy of the error message would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks connection string should use PWD instead of PASSWORD.
Have you tried the following?

```
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3307 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PWD=" + password + ";";
```

Comment: So how I can connect from remote php client ?

Comment: yes,php code in description, simpe mysqli connection

Comment: No I dont know how to do it, but I've tried from MySql workbench - no connection.

Comment: I updated my answer while you were writing your last comment. Could you check the connection string?

Comment: PWD or PASSWORD - no connection=(